# Android Marshmallow keeps moving apps to internal storage after update

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, app2sd, adoptable-storage

I have a 32Gb SD card as adopted storage in my phone with Android M. It should be considered as the default installation storage for apps, as I have migrated the data to it.

However, I still experience the annoying situation of having to manually move apps back to SD card every time they update (as in Lollipop). Actually it's even worse because the migration systematically fails at the first try saying "Couldn't move app. Internal error". The second try always works. I guess data from the new version clashes with data already in SD card from previous version, and it's deleted when error message pops up, so at second try there's no conflict.

How can I fix this? I'd like to get apps updated directly to SD card, which is how supposedly adopted storage should be working.

Comment: What's the phone you are using?  I'm experiencing the same exact issue (down to the "Couldn't move..." error) on my Moto X Play running the official 6.0 firmware.

Comment: I have a Moto G3 running official 6.0 firmware as well.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable.html):

> Apps can be placed on adopted storage media only when the developer has indicated support through the android:installLocation attribute.

The problem is that some apps that deny this support can be forcibly moved anyways, which it sounds like you're doing when you ignore that error and try the process again.  From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3oz7eu/guidelines_for_marshmallow_users_formatting/):

> I have seen screenshots (see this post [by Austin Pinto on eyes-free google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/eyes-free/rspqjlmu_ss/ouM7TMH-BQAJ), where that device running Marshmallow IS allowing moving all apps (though still excluding system and built-in apps). That is, it is violating the developer's preference for where the app should be installed.

So when the app updates, the Play Store is simply following exactly where the app tells it to be installed.

So, your options are:

- Stop moving those apps
- Ask the developers to add support for this feature
- Stop updating those apps

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Motorola G⁶ and before this all started happening, it was working PERFECTLY fine up until I got several error messages saying that certain applications stopped working. Then, I had to uninstall and reinstall all those applications. Then, some of my Microsoft applications started acting up as well, and those happen to be the ones I can move. They were in the Secure Digital card before, but after awhile, they were gone because of that error. Please let me know when someone has a solution to this.