# When phone starts to use adoptable storage?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I've recently set 50% of SD card as adoptable, and everything went fine partition is showed in settings, but phone doesn't use it I have installed some apps and they all went in internal partition not adopted one.
When will phone start to use adopted memory, when I run out of internal?
An also can I use adopted storage to save files for example from chrome since it only uses internal memory it's imposible to download on external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There isn't any rule which says *move apps to SD under so and so condition*.
- Apps don't move on their own into the ext.SD card (which is now a part of internal storage, since you *adopted* it). You need to *migrate* them as described [in DiAlex'sanswer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/142904/131553). Also note that some apps ( poorly designed ) after being [updated may be 
  restored in device storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/139691/131553) You will again need to *migrate* them)
- You can move app data or store anything (media, files)  if the app can access it ( I am not sure about Chrome as I don't use adoptable storage)
- For a better understanding of how memory is treated see [Mathew's answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/152313/131553)

Comment: one more question does I have to use migrate option from internal or adopted partition because I have that option only on 3-dot menu in adopted partition, on internal there isn't 3-dot menu at all..?

Comment: I have LG K350nds (K8). Sorry for bother you I presed migrate on adopted partition and now I can move apps between partitions, thank you.